# Count something in Unity Shader and output to script

Tags: unity-game-engine

Recently I want to do some image processing in Unity with Unity Shader.

There's a task of counting something over the pixels. For example, count the number of all black pixels in the image and output the number to script.

I know this can be implemented in script with `for` iteration. I am wondering if there's some way to do this job in shader.

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to output the count in texture.

Comment: What Draco18s wanted to say I guess is that we don't think there is a way to make a "normal" component script communicate with a shader / receiving an output value of a shader.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment (pixel) shaders cannot access any values from other fragments, as they are essentially run in parallel, so there's no possibility of accessing the same variable (i.e. couting pixels), even if you're fine with storing output value as a texture.

Answer (score 0):

Counting can be parallel. The main point is how to transfer the counting result. I do this with downsampling. I split image into grids and do counting inside the every grid. The result of each grid is saved and output with fragment shader. I repeat this until I get a 1x1 texture.